# grep for multiple strings in speedtest output

Tags: text-processing, macos

I'm using [speedtest](https://www.speedtest.net/) CLI in a BASH script and trying to grab the output by using only one line if possible.

Typical output of Speedtest:

```
Speedtest by Ookla

  Server: (censored)
     ISP: (censored)
 Latency:    93.85 ms   (222.66 ms jitter)
Download:    85.75 Mbps (data used: 134.8 MB)                               
  Upload:     5.68 Mbps (data used: 6.2 MB)
```

I would like to grab Latency, Download speed, Upload speed, and jitter.

```
Most ideal format: 
Download Speed: xx Mbps
Upload Speed: xx Mbps
Latency: xx ms
Jitter: xx ms
```

My current test code is using 2 wasteful statements:

```
dl_speed=`speedtest | grep "Download: " | head -2 | tail -1 | awk {'print$2'} | cut -f1 -d:`

ul_speed=`speedtest | grep "Upload: " | head -2 | tail -1 | awk {'print$2'} | cut -f1 -d:`

echo "Download Speed: $dl_speed Mbps"
echo "Upload Speed: $ul_speed Mbps"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GNU awk. I used at least one space and `(` as field separators. Append this to your `speedtest` command.

```
| awk 'BEGIN{ FS=" +|\\(" };
       /Download/{ dow=$3 " " $4 };
       /Upload/  { upl=$3 " " $4 };
       /Latency/ { lat=$3 " " $4 };
       /jitter/  { jit=$6 " " $7 };
       END{
         print "Download Speed:", dow;
         print "Upload Speed:", upl;
         print "Latency:", lat;
         print "Jitter:", jit
       }'
```

Output to stdout:

```
Download Speed: 85.75 Mbps
Upload Speed: 5.68 Mbps
Latency: 93.85 ms
Jitter: 222.66 ms
```

Answer (score 3):

```
speedtest | tr -d '(:'  | \
  awk '/Download|Upload/ {print $1 " Speed: ",$2,$3} 
       /Latency/ {print $1":",$2,$3} 
       /jitter/ {print "Jitter:",$4,$5}'
```

gives

```
Latency: 93.85 ms
Jitter: 222.66 ms
Download Speed:  85.75 Mbps
Upload Speed:  5.68 Mbps
```

Answer (score 3):

The versions of this tool (`speedtest-cli`) that I have access to (2.1.2 on Ubuntu and 2.1.3 on both macOS and OpenBSD) does not give the exact output format that you show.  It does, however, provide output in both CSV and JSON format if given the correct command line options.

This means that you could easily get the data that you require from e.g. the JSON formatted output like so:

```bsh
speedtest-cli --json | 
jq -r '[
    ["Download (Mbps):", .download/1e6],
    ["Upload (Mbps):", .upload/1e6],
    ["Latency (ms):", .server.latency]
] | map(@tsv)[]'
```

This picks out the `.download` key's value along with `.upload` and the `.latency` value from the `.server` sub-object.  The download and upload speed values are in bits/s, so they need to be scaled appropriately.  The values are outputted with headers in a tab-delimited manner.

Example of output:

```
Download (Mbps):        88.32191644148061
Upload (Mbps):  93.34628783248138
Latency (ms):   10.756
```

The variant of this tool that I have does not seem to output "jitter" in any of it output modes.

---

For reference, the full JSON output may look like

```json
{
  "download": 88321916.4414806,
  "upload": 93346287.83248138,
  "ping": 10.756,
  "server": {
    "url": "http://somehost.example.com:8080/speedtest/upload.php",
    "lat": "XXX",
    "lon": "YYY",
    "name": "Thetown",
    "country": "Thecountry",
    "cc": "ZZ",
    "sponsor": "Company",
    "id": "XYZ",
    "host": "somehost.example.com:8080",
    "d": 156.5033515123062,
    "latency": 10.756
  },
  "timestamp": "2021-12-04T20:12:20.816506Z",
  "bytes_sent": 119447552,
  "bytes_received": 110800036,
  "share": null,
  "client": {
    "ip": "my-public-ip-number",
    "lat": "XX",
    "lon": "YY",
    "isp": "provider",
    "isprating": "3.7",
    "rating": "0",
    "ispdlavg": "0",
    "ispulavg": "0",
    "loggedin": "0",
    "country": "ZZ"
  }
}
```

---

You could also parse the CSV output from `speedtest-cli` using [the `csvkit` tools](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```bsh
{ speedtest-cli --csv-header; speedtest-cli --csv; } |
csvcut -c Download,Upload,Ping | csvlook
```

This first outputs the CSV headers from `speedtest-cli` (which, for whatever reason, needs to be done separately).  It then runs the speed test, extracts the `Download`, `Upload` and `Ping` columns (there does not seem to be a "Latency" column when getting the result as CSV), and reformats the resulting CSV into a Markdown-formatted table.

The result may look something like

```
|        Download |          Upload |   Ping |
| --------------- | --------------- | ------ |
| 88,649,466.475… | 93,164,137.292… | 10.193 |
```

Which looks like this when rendered:

| Download | Upload | Ping |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 88,649,466.475… | 93,164,137.292… | 10.193 |

Note that the numbers in the first two columns are in bits/s.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{if ($1 ~ /Download/){print  "Download speed: " $2 " mbps"}else{if($1 ~ /Upload/){print "Upload Speed: "$2 " mbps"}else{if($NF ~ /jitter/  && $1 ~ /Latency/){gsub(/\(/,"",$(NF-2));print "Latency :" $2 " ms\n jitter: " $(NF-2)" ms"}}}}' filename

Latency :93.85 ms
 jitter: 222.66 ms
Download speed: 85.75 mbps
Upload Speed: 5.68 mbps
```

Answer (score -1):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box and only using the data names in your code once, when you need to print them, so you could trivially add additional `prt()` statements, modify them, test them, and/or reorder them for this or any other similarly-formatted data without having to make any other changes to the code:

```
$ speedtest | awk '
    {
        gsub(/[:()]/,"")
        tag2val[tolower($1)] = $2 " " $3
        tag2val[tolower($6)] = $4 " " $5
    }
    END {
        prt("Download Speed")
        prt("Upload Speed")
        prt("Latency")
        prt("Jitter")
    }
    function prt(name,      tag) {
        tag = tolower(name)
        sub(/ .*/,"",tag)
        print name ":" OFS tag2val[tag]
    }
'
Download Speed: 85.75 Mbps
Upload Speed: 5.68 Mbps
Latency: 93.85 ms
Jitter: 222.66 ms
```